# unable to compile spring project

Tags: java, spring, maven

While setting up a new spring project, I am facing issue during

```
maven compile
```

Following is my barebones pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.taobao</groupId>
    <artifactId>toughlib</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>some-random-id</id>
            <name>some random name</name>
            <url>http://internal-repo:8081/artifactory/internal</url>
        </repository>
    </distributionManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.1-RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

I have tried following combinations

- changing the URL of the repository above to https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework
- removing repo specification in pom.xml completely

All of them lead to the same error below

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project toughlib: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.taobao:toughlib:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:4.2.1-RELEASE in myorg (https://artifactory.myenv.com/repo) -> [Help 1]
```

I can see that the required dependency is available in ~/.m2 directory as
repository/org/springframework/spring-webmvc/4.2.1-RELEASE/

Any clues how to go about fixing it?

Following are the versions of things involved

- Apache Maven 3.3.9
- Java version: 1.8.0_101, vendor: Oracle
  Corporation

Comment: It is probably `4.2.1.RELEASE` instead of `4.2.1-RELEASE`

Comment: You should perhaps check your settings.xml for proper settings

Comment: you both were correct. I had already removed settings.xml but missed the dot thing. super thanks